# url amigável com vários paramteros no htaccess

Tags: htaccess

eu vejo que alguns sites como olx, buscape entre outros, quando enviado vários parâmetros na url é separado esses parâmetros por / ou -.

Por exemplo: 
http://sc.olx.com.br/norte-de-santa-catarina/imoveis/casas-a-partir-de-450-00-reais-118704544

Preciso de ajuda para eliminar o ? e o & e separar por /.

Exemplo:

site.com.br/imovel?id=3366

Deixar dessa forma:

site.com.br/imovel/3366

Meu htaccess esta configurado dessa forma mas não esta funcionando:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?pagina=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^exclusive/imovel/(\d+)$ imovel?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^exclusive/lista/(\d+)$ lista?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Estou utilizando php e a função pra manipular a url esta assim:

```
function getHome(){
        $url = $_GET['pagina'];
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        $url[0] = ($url[0] == NULL ? 'content' : $url[0]);


        if(file_exists('tpl/'.$url[0].'.php')){
            require_once('tpl/'.$url[0].'.php');
        }elseif(file_exists('/tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php')){
            require_once('tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php');
        }elseif(file_exists('/tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'/'.$url[2].'.php')){
            require_once('tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'/'.$url[2].'.php');
        }else{
            require_once('tpl/404.php');
        }
```

Comment: acredito que o seu problema não está no htaccess. O problema está em como a sua aplicação interpreta as urls chamadas.

Comment: Igor, a sua aplicação foi desenvolvida em qual linguagem? Você está utilizando algum framework?

Comment: Estou usando php, porém sem Framework.

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Substitua as três últimas linhas por RewriteRule .* index.php

Depois manipule o conteúdo de $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ].

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Jaiber, pode me mostrar um exemplo da utilização do $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] para manipulação da url no php?

Comment: Construí um framerwork hmvc que utiliza o seguinte .htaccess por padrão:  

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^public/css/?(.*) style.php
RewriteRule ^jf/public/?(.*) core/public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !style.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sitemap.xml

RewriteRule .* index.php`

Comment: No PHP, utilize ...

`<?php

$urlBase = dirname( $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] );
if ( substr( $urlBase, -1 ) !== '/' ) {
    $urlBase        .= '/';
}

$controller = 'webapp';
$action = 'home';
$params = array();

$urlRequest = substr( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], strlen( $urlBase ) );`

Comment: `if ( $urlRequest ) {
    $requestExploded = explode( '/', $urlRequest );
    $controller = array_shift( $requestExploded );
    
    count( $requestExploded ) && $action = array_shift( $requestExploded );

    if ( $qtdParams = count( $requestExploded ) ) {
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $qtdParams; $i += 2 ) {
            $key = $requestExploded[ $i ];
            $value = $i + 1 < $qtdParams ? $requestExploded[ $i + 1 ] : null;
            $params[ $key ] = $value;
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: `define( 'CONTROLLER', $controller );
define( 'ACTION', $action );
define( 'PARAMS', implode( '/', $params ) );

define( 'URL_BASE', $urlBase );
define( 'URL_REQUEST', $urlRequest );
`

Pronto

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar o código.

Comment: Blz, espero que ajude.